# How can I print the data contained by a C++ Map while debugging using DBX

Tags: dictionary, dbx

I want to know the contents of a Map while debugging a c++ program.
I am using command line dbx.

I have pointer to the map.

Is there a way in which i can get the data printed.

--

Edit: 
p *dataMap will give me this::

```
 p *dataMap
*dataMap = {
    __t = {
        __buffer_size   = 32U
        __buffer_list   = {
            __data_ = 0x3ba2b8
        }
        __free_list     = (nil)
        __next_avail    = 0x474660
        __last          = 0x474840
        __header        = 0x3b97b8
        __node_count    = 76U
        __insert_always = false
        __key_compare   = {
/* try using "print -r" to see any inherited members */
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Alok Kr.

Comment: I generally debug C using DBX. Doesn't `print *ptr` work for you?

Comment: No, it wont work. Please check the edit

Comment: `__next_avail`, `__header` are pointers and you want to see their contents?

Comment: No, basically what i want is that I can access the key and values pair of the map. Can there be some way?

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a ksh function to pretty print map, here is an example :

put following line in .dbxrc

source /ksh_STL_map

in dbx, use ppp to call ksh function that define in ksh_STL_map:

(dbx) ppp k

k = 2 elems {343, 0x301f8; 565, 0x30208}

I tried to post content of ksh_STL_map here, but this editor format will mess up the content, it's better that you post your email, then I can send ksh_STL_map directly to you.

Comment: Thanks, my mail-id is : alokkumar416@gmail.com

Comment: @chichin ko: Hey can you please mail the function to me, or put it here.

Comment: Kumar: I just send ksh_STL_map to you via email

Comment: can we not post emails and post the code here for others?